# How to swipe Enable on react-native-tab-navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using react-native-tab-navigator. How can i swipe between tabs and screen As far as i know react-navigation tab-navigator have a props like Swipe Enable = true But in react-native-tab-navigator doesn't have a props like this. So, what's possible solutions for that ?